# How to track usage stats of my react-native design library component?

Tags: react-native, components

I am building a UI component library on React-Native for consumption by multiple apps. I'd like to set up some analytics on which components from the library are used most, by which (internal) repos, etc. I see that Figma offers something close but I don't see any other solution (and we don't use Figma) - Is there anyway to do this?